# How to have a completely customised navigation bar for IOS using XCODE Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I need to **customize my navigation bar** in my xcode project in such a way (**as shown in figure below**)

[image]

that there is an **increase in height** of navigation bar, and there is a  **search bar in the middle** and a **home button to the left** and a **help button to the right**.**country and account access on the the top right aside to the help button**. I want to make this navigation bar available in all screens in my application.

Please ask me if you need anymore information regarding the question.

Comment: Use navigation bar, left bar buttons, right bar button etc.

Comment: then where will i give that country and account access. i tried the suggested method, but there is no space to give those two buttons.

Comment: you can add multiple bar buttons items. Or even you can customize it

Comment: check there is a property  `NSArray<UIBarButtonItem *> *leftBarButtonItems` and `rightBarButtons` for `UINavigationItem` u can set multiple items

Comment: what i m asking is how to do that. see this is the design i need, i m ready to compromise it, if i could add multiple buttons to navigation bar neatly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following steps:

> 1. Hide your navigation bar.
> 2. Add UIView with same frame as Navigation bar (0, 0, 320, 64)
> 3. Use UIButton instead of BarButtonItem and UILabel in place of navigation titlebar
> 4. And your customised navigation bar design is ready!!
> 5. Now set actions on Left button to perform pop operation.

Try and let me know, if you can’t do it.

Comment: Note; Here is sample frame for navigation bar. Use autolayout constraints to set frame of your customized navigation bar

Comment: do you know how to reduce the size of navigation bar. i tried the so many methods nothing is working.

Comment: Do you dealing with default navigation bar? or using custom?

Also when do you want to reduce it's height, during scrolling of other contents or permanent fix reduces size?

Raise a new question and send me link here. I'll help you to solve your problem

Comment: I m using the default navigation bar. but i m not being able to reduce its height from 44. i tried changing it in source code of main story board, by setting the frames in code. is there any other ways that works